# Uploading Image URL to Firestore

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui

I am trying to make an app like Tinder and I did the auth part :

```
      Button(action: {
                                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result,error) in
                                    if error != nil{
                                        self.error = error?.localizedDescription ?? ""
                                        self.alert.toggle()
                                    }else{
                                        let db = Firestore.firestore()
                                        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                                    db.collection("Users").document(user ?? "").setData(["Name": name,"Lastname":lastname,"Gender" : gender])
                                        self.next.toggle()
                                        print("success")
                                    }
                                }
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Register")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(.system(size: 24))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                    .background(
                                        Color.white
                                            .frame(width: 300, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                                            .cornerRadius(20)
                                            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 1, x: 0, y: 5)
                                    )
                            })
```

But I couldn't figure out how to add photoURL to Firestore. Can you guys help me to find solution I am very new to Firebase

Thanks to comments I did some research and I write this code. It works just like I wanted. I can upload image Storage and I can store URL in Firestore. If someone want to use or trying to learn here is my code :

```
 func uploadImage(image: UIImage){
    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1){
        let storage = Storage.storage()
            storage.reference().child("temp").putData(imageData, metadata: nil){ (data, err) in
            if let err = err{
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                print("Image uploaded")
            }
                let url = storage.reference().child("temp")
                url.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    if error != nil{
                        print("error")
                    }else{
                        self.photoURL = "\(url!)"
                        let db = Firestore.firestore()
                        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
                        db.collection("Users").document(user!.uid).updateData(["photoURL" : photoURL])
                        
                    }
                }
        }
    }else{
        print("Could not unwrap/case image to data")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add a selected image from gallery to `Firestore` or an image `URL`?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Image URL. I have a button which uploads selected image to storage but it is a UIImage. I can't use UIImage with WebImage(SDWebImageSwiftUI). I want it just like Tinder. After authentication I have NavigationLink for addImageView. In that view I have 4 button when I tapped button I wanted to uploadImage and wanted to show uploaded Image at the same time. After that in MainView I need Image URL s to show images(with WebImage) so people swipe right or left.

Comment: You should explicitly handle when `user` is `nil`. Using `.document(user ?? "")` will still throw an error even if you made the syntax error go away.

Comment: What's preventing you from saving a `photoURL` field to the `/Users/{userId}` document like you are for name and gender?

Comment: I don't know how ? I have ImagePicker when I tap button ImagePicker opens and I can upload images to Storage but I couldn't figure out how to upload URL to Firestore. I need @State property I guess but I don't know how to do it I am newbie

Comment: I think your asking how to upload an image to Firebase Storage and then save the URL to Firebase Firestore??  If so, that's covered right in the documentation [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file). See in the code this section `riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in` which you can then store that url in Firestore. Are asking about `photoURL` as part of the Auth variable like [Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) - photoURL?

Comment: @Batuhan, you should post what worked as an answer instead of editing your question